# How can I implement the back navigation when clicked on GamepadB button on XBOX controller

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp

Gamepad B button is suspending the app instead of back navigation.

I'm trying to develop a UWP app using the WebView but when I try to do the back navigation in the app by clicking the "B" button on the Gamepad it is suspending the whole app and returning to the home page is there anyway how I can implement the back key functionality for the XBOX controller.

For example if I'm in the Netflix home page and if I click on any show it'll navigate me to the details page of that content. From there if I click on back it should navigate back to the home page instead of suspending the whole app.

Mainpage

```xml
<WebView Source="https://luser.github.io/gamepadtest/">
</WebView>
```

This is the webview part that I've used till now and made some changes by using the GoBack() functionality provided in the documentation but still facing the same issue like the back navigation is not working at all.

'MainPage.xaml.cs'

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
}

private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.GamepadB)
    {
        if(source.CanGoBack)
        {
            source.GoBack();
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown -= CoreWindow_KeyDown;
}
```

Am I missing anything which is causing this issue or is there any other method that I've to use to get the required functionality.

I'm setting the `**navigation.gamepadInputEmulation = 'keyboard':**`

Thank you in advance for taking your time to look at the question and helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried with some other methods that has been provided in the documentation and Forums but none of them has worked for me. So, here's the solution which worked for me well.

I've added one event listener to capture the button click events in the XBOX controller instead of having a loop to check which button is pressed I've replaced it with "document.addEventListener" which will not give any events when tried on the Browser but will be able to capture the keyCodes when run in XBOX console.

Here, when we use the addEventListener the keyCodes will differ from the actual keycodes that are provided in the documentation. Here, we'll be getting the keycode as '196' for GamepadB button. After adding this line able to disable the default functionality.

```
if (ev.keyCode === 196) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. Happy coding!!!